# How Can I access the key in subclass of CombinerFn when combining a PCollection of KV pairs?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm implementing the [CombinePerKeyExample](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/cookbook/CombinePerKeyExamples.java) using a subclass of `CombineFn` instead of using an implementation of `SerializableFunction`

```java
package me.examples;

import org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.AvroCoder;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.DefaultCoder;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Combine.CombineFn;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class ConcatWordsCombineFn extends CombineFn<String, ConcatWordsCombineFn.Accumulator, String> {
    @DefaultCoder(AvroCoder.class)
    public static class Accumulator{
        HashSet<String> plays;
    }

    @Override
    public Accumulator createAccumulator(){
        Accumulator accumulator = new Accumulator();
        accumulator.plays = new HashSet<>();
        return accumulator;
    }

    @Override
    public Accumulator addInput(Accumulator accumulator, String input){
        accumulator.plays.add(input);
        return accumulator;
    }

    @Override
    public Accumulator mergeAccumulators(Iterable<Accumulator> accumulators){
        Accumulator mergeAccumulator = new Accumulator();
        mergeAccumulator.plays = new HashSet<>();

        for(Accumulator accumulator: accumulators){
            mergeAccumulator.plays.addAll(accumulator.plays);
        }

        return mergeAccumulator;
    }

    @Override
    public String extractOutput(Accumulator accumulator){
        //how to access the key here ? 
        return String.join(",", accumulator.plays);
    }
}
```

The pipeline is composed of a `ReadFromBigQuery`, `ExtractAllPlaysOfWords` (code below) and `WriteToBigQuery`

```java
package me.examples;

import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.KvCoder;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.StringUtf8Coder;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Combine;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.PTransform;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.KV;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;

public class PlaysForWord extends PTransform<PCollection<TableRow>, PCollection<TableRow>> {


    @Override
    public PCollection<TableRow> expand(PCollection<TableRow> input) {

            PCollection<KV<String, String>> largeWords = input.apply("ExtractLargeWords", ParDo.of(new ExtractLargeWordsFn()));
            PCollection<KV<String, String>> wordNPlays = largeWords.apply("CombinePlays",Combine.perKey(new ConcatWordsCombineFn()));
            wordNPlays.setCoder(KvCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of(), StringUtf8Coder.of()));
            PCollection<TableRow> rows = wordNPlays.apply("FormatToRow", ParDo.of(new FormatShakespeareOutputFn()));
            return rows;
    }
}
```

I would like to access the key in `ConcatWordsCombineFn` in order to do the final accumulation based on that. An example can be to join the words with `,` if the key begins with an `a` or use `;` otherwise.

When looking at the programming guide

> If you need the combining strategy to change based on the key (for example, MIN for some users and MAX for other users), **you can define a KeyedCombineFn** to access the key within the combining strategy.

I couldn't find `KeyedCombineFn` in `org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Combine`
I'm using Apache Beam 2.12.0 and Google Dataflow as a runner.

Comment: I filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-7508 as a feature request for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a built-in way to solve this. The straightforward workaround (not perfect, I know) is to wrap your string into another KV: `KV<String, KV<String, String>>` where both keys are the same.

Comment: We can even format the value to contain the key and keep the KV<String, String> type. In absence of a built-in feature I'm considering this as the answer.